# В каких случаях нужно писать staticmethod-функцию класса вместо отдельной за пределами класса?

Tags: python, static

К сожалению, у меня нет понимания зачем в Python нужны статические методы классов. Т.е. методы, которые мы объявляем с помощью `@staticmethod`

Есть мнение, что они нужны для создания утилитарных функций, т.е. когда нам хочется показать связь функции с определенным классом, но при этом мы не хотим давать ей доступ к внутренностям объектов.

Но ведь эту цель можно достичь и по другому: положить в тот же модуль, где расположен сам класс.

Разместив функцию `pretty_print()` в модуле `test_sample.py`, там же где расположен класс `TestSample`, мне кажется, что читателю кода достаточно легко понять, что `test_sample.pretty_print()` ничто иное как утилитарная функция и тем самым мне нет смысла помещать её внутрь класса, чтоб иметь непонятную (пока непонятную) возможность писать `TestSample.pretty_print()`.

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти хоть один нормальный пример из жизни, когда статические методы действительно нужны и полезны.

Comment: В питоне модули могут, в некоторых вещах, классы заменить (вы в них можете создавать переменные-поля, функции, что работают с переменными модуля), например, в java вы не сможете вне класса функцию разместить. А так, действительно, статичные методы в классе не так очевидно полезны, как например методы класса (@classmethod) и вынос их из класса может не вызвать логических вопросов

Comment: Таким образом в питоне реализуются основные принципы ООП: инкапсуляция, полиморфизм (можно переопределить стат функцию в наследнике), абстракция. В принципе, можно вообще без классов обойтись, одними только функциями. Так что использование классов и стат функций - это ваш выбор. Я не эксперт, это просто мое мнение.

Comment: Да, это скорее организационный вопрос. Ну тут нужно смотреть, какую работу выполняет метод, к чему его функционал ближе - к задачам модуля в целом или к функционалу конкретного класса внутри этого модуля. Кроме того, чем глубже по иерархии вы размещаете какой-то метод, тем меньше вероятность, что его имя перекроет  другую переменную или метод с таким же именем, потому что обращаться к нему скорее всего нужно будет с дополнительным префиксом в виде имени класса. Особенно это актуально для любителей делать `from module import *`.

Comment: Наверное самый лучший пример из документации cpython, там они используются как служебные для своего класса, для лучшего сокрытия частных методов def _xxx и т.д. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py

Answer (score 2):

Начнём с того, что статические методы в Python эквивалентны таковым в Java/C++ и фактически являются просто функциями, т.к. не имеют доступа ни к атрибутам класса, ни к объекту.

**Official Python Docs** ([link](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#staticmethod)):

> Like all decorators, it is also possible to call staticmethod as a
> regular function and do something with its result. This is needed in
> some cases where you need a reference to a function from a class body
> and you want to avoid the automatic transformation to instance method.
> For these cases, use this idiom:
>
> ```py
> def regular_function():
>     ...
>
> class C:
>     method = staticmethod(regular_function)
> ```

Это собственно всё, что там сказано про применение.

**Отсебятина:**

- Когда необходимо продекорировать некоторые методы класса, сам декоратор помечается как `@staticmethod`, т.к. `self` передаётся во вложенную функцию. Мне лично кажется логически правильно не выделять декоратору область видимости всего модуля.
- Группировка функций: выделение функций в логические категории через пространство имён класса в пределах модуля

Ну и утилитарное использование, конечно.

*В комментариях хорошо объяснили тоже.* Всё на ваш вкус!